# How to use join instead of union in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have four table in database T1,T2,T3,T4 .I have to consider both the result of T3 and T4(but cannot join them together as it omits some rows) I tried the below query and it works

```
select * from T1
join T2 on T1.a=T2.a
join T3 on T3.b=T2.b
union
select * from T1
join T2 on T1.a=T2.a
join T4 on T4.b=T1.b
```

Is there any way to consider both the table without using the union?

Comment: are you using sql server or mysql? the answer depends on it

Comment: I am using MYSQL

Answer (score 1):

The `UNION` is fine. There isn't a simplest solution for this query.